# Android Resource Linking Failed values, styles.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, build.gradle

> So i want to create a new android project then suddenly i have this error saying Android Resource Linking Failed and below here is my code.

**Styles.xml**

```
resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style type ="attr" name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item type="attr" name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item type="attr" name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item type="attr" name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Error Shown**

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Rapih\Re_Mind\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka app.com.re_mind:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this do not add type attribute. this might help you.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please try to remove  type="attr"  in all tags